# adding a fixed matrix to a list of matrices

Tags: r, matrix

suppose I have the following list

```
l1 = list()
for(i in 1:5){
 l1[[i]] = matrix(rnorm(9),3)
}
```

Now, I want to the following diagonal matrix to each of the matrices in `l1`

```
My_D = diag(c(1:3))
```

what is the efficient way to add `My_D` to `l1`

I tried the following and non-worked

```
l1 + My_D
lapply(l1, function(i) l1[[i]] + My_D)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do it with `lapply` in this way:

With `lapply` we can iterate over each matrix in `l1`.

`function(x) x + My_D` will add `My_D` to each matrix mat in the list.

```
lapply(l1, function(x) x + My_D)

[[1]]
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  1.3232960  1.2963813 -0.8209761
[2,] -0.9243988  1.1403460 -0.1451593
[3,] -2.1092458 -0.1841043  4.1437289

[[2]]
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,]  0.5765338 0.8482495  0.558125
[2,] -0.1517627 3.5162358 -1.251998
[3,] -0.6023508 1.6212503  1.871297

[[3]]
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.2219524 -1.9098658 -0.7784212
[2,] -1.0356978 -0.0148585  1.1690386
[3,]  0.9394348  0.2223198  2.9638898

[[4]]
            [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  1.40803158  1.177378  0.2193847
[2,] -0.45375624  2.656497 -0.7228035
[3,]  0.08309659 -2.308122  2.5135570

[[5]]
           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  0.3835801 -1.250286 -0.8052156
[2,] -1.3480947  2.109671  1.2550385
[3,]  0.9339825  1.188224  3.9017532
```

Answer (score 3):

a one-liner:

```
1:5 |> Map(f = \(i) matrix(rnorm(9),3) + diag(1:3))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `+`

```
lapply(l1, `+`, My_D)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Map` as well

```
> Map(`+`, l1, list(My_D))
[[1]]
           [,1]         [,2]      [,3]
[1,]  1.0739486 -0.001785253 0.3182650
[2,] -0.8990085  0.734136730 0.4335584
[3,] -2.0633130  1.739067118 2.7205794

[[2]]
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  1.1109062 -1.2169344 -0.2388589
[2,] -0.2476381 -0.2192969  0.8789234
[3,] -0.2640300  0.2979124  2.1932904

[[3]]
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.1121753  0.9033144  2.7007893
[2,]  1.3092684  2.6540939 -0.6647356
[3,] -0.3375710 -0.2758829  5.2177263

[[4]]
           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  0.1994354 0.9156980 -0.7446266
[2,] -0.2939871 1.9025079 -0.1368127
[3,]  0.9149957 0.1669993  4.2053365

[[5]]
           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  1.7506555 0.7705074 -1.7272950
[2,] -1.1165370 2.8796652  0.5295734
[3,] -0.0623417 0.3847098  3.6640302
```